# Why doesn't TikZ accept conditional colors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, definition

I want to use conditional colors.

I produced the following MWE but it does not work. What is the issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

%\def\versionNB{}
\def\versionColor{}

% -----------------------------------%
%
\newcommand{\conditionalColor}[2]
{%
\ifdefined\versionNB
    #1
\else
    #2
\fi}

\def\myColor{\conditionalColor{black}{blue}}
% -----------------------------------%

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill, \myColor]  (0, 0) circle (0.75pt) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why so complicated? Why don't you simply use `mycolor` and define it as `\colorlet{mycolor}{blue} ` or `\colorlet{mycolor}{black}`?

Comment: also why define `\conditionalColor` to expand to `black<space>` and `blue<space>` ?

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle. I don't know when `<space>` are important or not...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because I need a general command for a project.

Comment: @Colas spacesarealmostalwaysimportantunlessyouareGermanlikeUlrike

Comment: @DavidCarlisle germansmakenospuriousspaceerrors.

Comment: sorry but there is no real difference between a special command and a special color name in such a place, only the second is much more natural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without tikz, if you add

```
{\color{\myColor} abc}
```

you would get

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `blue '.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.22 {\color{\myColor}
                       abc}
?
```

as `\myColor` expands to `blue<space>`

You intended

```
\newcommand{\conditionalColor}[2]
{%
\ifdefined\versionNB
    #1%
\else
    #2%
\fi}
```

and then your original works (probably by accident) you can't really rely on a command key-val parser recognising `\myColor` as a known key as it expands to a color name. also you are testing on every use it would be more robust to use a defined color (not a macro) `mycolor` and just do the conditional test once at the point of definition, defining this to be blue or black

Comment: I would to provide to authors a simple method to define a conditional color. Hence the command `\conditionalColor{}{}`. Do you have a suggestion? Thanks

Comment: @Colas why? why force new syntax on them, just use a specific colorname and let them define it.  if you use `mycolor`  users can define `mycolor` however they like.

Comment: Every author can create its own colors but with two cases: the B&W book and the colored PDF.